# Question about Sharepoint 2010 Limited Access permissions

Tags: permissions, sharepoint-enterprise

I have three groups in a sharepoint site
Members- Contribute, Limited Access
Owners -  Full Control,Limited Access
Visitors - Read, Limited Access

why does it say limited access?any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Limited Access means a SharePoint user or group has permissions to an item or document or page or library *within* a Site, but does not have permissions to the entire Site.

This is normally used when you want to share content that resides within a site with users but not allow to browse the site.

See the following [Microsoft TechNet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc721640.aspx) for further help on the subject.